# what is the formula for finding the Future value of Monthly deposited money?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education

So, question is I have $100 to invest at end of each month with annual interest rate of 5% and money is being deposited for 10 years. what is the future value.
but I need the formula that is used. thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SE! What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I was using this formula FV = PV(1+r)^n. where FV is future value and PV is present. r is the interest rate and n is the number of periods of deposits. but the answer I was getting is wrong. I am suppose to get answer between 15500+ but I am getting the wrong answer at 6million 500

Comment: How much money should you have after one year, after two years, can you find a general pattern?

Comment: @QasimIqbal  I don't like blindly using formulas, the more you use them without proving them the more drifting away from good mathematics. Use the pattern method I shown, and prove that the pattern you see will always hold.

Comment: ok. thanks for your response I will try to find pattern